# error: expected primary-expression before 'float'

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, vector, operator-overloading

I am having some odd behavior from two of my functions. both are erroring when they are getting called in the build process. I am not to sure what it is I am missing as everything looks fine to me but that is obviously not the case.

First line with the error:

```
matf4x4 perspective = perspective(m_fov, m_aspect, m_near, m_far); // ERROR (1)
```

Perspective function definition:

```
static mat4x4<float> perspective(float fov, float aspect, float n, float f) {
    float q = 1.0f / tanf(radians(0.5f * fov));
    float A = q / aspect;
    float B = (n + f) / (n - f);
    float C = (2.0f * n * f) / (n - f);

    mat4x4<float> result;

    result[0] = vec4f(A, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    result[1] = vec4f(0.0f, q, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    result[2] = vec4f(0.0f, 0.0f, B, -1.0f);
    result[3] = vec4f(0.0f, 0.0f, C, 0.0f);

    return result;
}
```

ERROR (1) output:

```
C:\Users\Matt\CLionProjects\SkyGames\Engine\Camera\Camera.cpp:18:66: error: no match for call to '(sky::matf4x4 {aka sky::mat4x4<float>}) (float&, float&, float&, float&)'
  matf4x4 perspective = perspective(m_fov, m_aspect, m_near, m_far);
```

Second line with error:

```
matf4x4 lookat = lookat<float>(m_position, centre, m_up); // ERROR (2)
```

Lookat function definition:

```
template <typename T>
static mat4x4<T> lookat(const vec3<T>& eye, const vec3<T>& centre, const vec3<T>& up) {
    vec3<T> f = normalize(centre - eye);
    vec3<T> upN = normalize(up);
    vec3<T> s = cross(f, upN);
    vec3<T> u = cross(s, f);
    mat4x4<T> M = mat4x4<T>(vec4<T>(s[0], u[0], -f[0], T(0)),
                            vec4<T>(s[1], u[1], -f[1], T(0)),
                            vec4<T>(s[2], u[2], -f[2], T(0)),
                            vec4<T>(T(0), T(0), T(0), T(1)));
    return M * translate<T>(-eye);
}
```

Matrix 4x4 float with operator overload =

```
mat4x4<T>&operator=(const mat4x4<T>& mat) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m_width; ++i)
        matrix[i] = mat.matrix[i];
    return *this;
}
```

ERROR(2) output:

```
C:\Users\Matt\CLionProjects\SkyGames\Engine\Camera\Camera.cpp:20:26: error: expected primary-expression before 'float'
  matf4x4 lookat = lookat<float>(m_position, centre, m_up);
```

Comment: Your variables have the same name as your functions. Rename either variables or functions and it should work.

Comment: thanks. that was really stupid. I changed the variable names earlier and did not realize that I was doing that.

Comment: that has worked thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change variable name or function name.

In statement `matf4x4 lookat = lookat<float>(...);` , the compiler first add variable `lookat` to its symbol table, so outer layer function `lookat` is hidden in current scope. When meet the second `lookat`, the compiler think it's the variable `lookat`.

Comment: completely correct about error 2 but error 1 was actually the same error as 2 as I am not passing constants to the function I am passing variables